# running Kafka on WSL and make producer on windows

Tags: java, windows, apache-kafka

I'm running Kafka on WSL. I'm trying to make simple producer like this (I'm using intellj)

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";

        //create Producer properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());

        //create the producer
        KafkaProducer<String,String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);

        //create a producer record
        ProducerRecord<String,String> record =
                new ProducerRecord<String, String>("first_topic","hallo world");

        //send data
        producer.send(record);

        //flush + close
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();
    }

}
```

but there's a problem, when I try to run the code it shows this error

```
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error connecting to node AD17-2.localdomain:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (AD17-2.localdomain)
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1495)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1354)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1288)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:403)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:151)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:955)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.sendProducerData(Sender.java:350)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:323)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Process finished with exit code -1
```

i even checked the port on my Windows

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:9092           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

my question is, is it impossible to make producer on windows and while running kafka on WSL ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Kafka broker is using the local hostname (`AD17-2.localdomain`) in its advertised listener. When you client connects to it initially on 127.0.0.1:9092 the broker returns this address for it to connect to for producing messages. Your producer fails to resolve this address, and fails.

To fix it, in the broker's `server.properties` set

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

More info: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me for **Apache Kafka 3.4.0**:

1. Change Apache Kafka's `server.properties`
2. Ask WSL2 to prefer **IPV4** over **IPV6**
3. Java code with producer to use WSL2 IP

**Step 1**

In WSL2 `config/server.properties`

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://[::1]:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
```

**Step 2**

You also have to tell WSL2 to prefer **IPV4** instead of **IPV6**[[1](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200257)], like so:

1. Edit the /etc/gai.conf

`$ sudo vi /etc/gai.conf`

2. At the end of the lines **uncomment the last 3 lines**, and you should have something like this:

```
#
# scopev4  <mask>  <value>
#    Add another rule to the RFC 6724 scope table for IPv4 addresses.
#    By default the scope IDs described in section 3.2 in RFC 6724 are
#    used.  Changing these defaults should hardly ever be necessary.
#    The defaults are equivalent to:
#
scopev4 ::ffff:169.254.0.0/112  2
scopev4 ::ffff:127.0.0.0/104    2
scopev4 ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96       14
```

**Step 3**

In Windows 10 Java Code:

1. Get the WSL2's IP first with this command: `hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f1`

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // WSL2 IP = 172.xx.xxx.xx:9092
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "172.xx.xxx.xx:9092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());

        try (KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)) {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> message = new ProducerRecord<>("test-topic", "Hello, World!");
            producer.send(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this solution:
Whit the command: "ip addr | grep eth0" on Ubuntu terminal I can get external interface IP, I set this IP on advertised.listener and with the command:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9092 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=9092 connectaddress=XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

on Windows cmd I can forward ports. With the command "netstat -ab" I can see on Windows cmd the IP and Port TCP 0.0.0.0:9092. It works correctly!
[Running Kafka Confluent Platform on WSL 2 (Ubuntu Distribution) and Spring application on Windows (Broker may not be available)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569699/running-kafka-confluent-platform-on-wsl-2-ubuntu-distribution-and-spring-appli)