# Running Kafka Confluent Platform on WSL 2 (Ubuntu Distribution) and Spring application on Windows (Broker may not be available)

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm running Confluent Platform in wsl 2(Ubuntu Distribution) and I also running a Spring application on Windows but when I send a message with a producer I have this error:

> Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

I have a look this articles:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/
and
https://forum.confluent.io/t/running-kafka-connect-sink-on-separate-machine-from-zookeeper-topic-non-localhost/3038
and
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

But I don't find the solution.

What is the configuration in concluent/etc/kafka/server.properties file?

I've set this:

> advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
> listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
> listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092

Kafka is running on: "localhost:9092" and within WSL2 I can send and read messages correctly but it doesn't work my spring boot application on Windows.

I see this answer, but It doesn't work in my localhost:
[running Kafka on WSL and make producer on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256604/running-kafka-on-wsl-and-make-producer-on-windows)

Do I have to change something in my Windows configuration? In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts?

Could you please advice how to solve this error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ifconfig` (or `ip addr`) inside WSL2 terminal, find its external interface IP, then use that as the advertised listener.

Then you'll need to use [`netsh interface portproxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy) command from Windows CMD to forward ports from the hypervisor to the host. This also assumes `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`

Example

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9092 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=9092 connectaddress=XXX.XX.XX.XX
```

Where `XXX.XX.XX.XX` is the IP from the interface address

Then connecting to `localhost` from Windows environment will forward requests to the hypervisor, which will return its advertised listener address.

You could also try using the IP of the hypervisor directly, rather than localhost / port forwarding

---

---

Or you can just use Docker for Windows, run Kafka and configure listeners there as containers with a port-forward, and it'll forward ports correctly from Windows host, on its own

Comment: Whit the command: "ip addr | grep eth0" on Ubuntu terminal I can get external interface IP, I set this IP on advertised.listener and with the command: "netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9092 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=9092 connectaddress=XXX.XX.XX.XX" on Windows cmd I can forward ports. With the command "netstat -ab" I can see on Windows cmd the IP and Port TCP 0.0.0.0:9092. It works correctly! Thanks!

Comment: @OneCricketer is there any article with detailed steps that I can follow? I am still pretty new to this.

Comment: @CS1999 The exact command was given in the previous comment, you just need to get the IP using the other shown command