# Communicate Kafka on Docker container over WSL2 and windows 11

Tags: docker, networking, apache-kafka, wsl-2, windows-11

I have docker-engine configured on WSL2 and Win11; and installed a simple kafka cluster for development testing, etc.
I have not installed docker-desktop and I do not want to install it but it seems that this part brings a series of configurations to be able to communicate with the windows host.
I have read several articles that talk about the subject, but it is not clear to me what is happening.
It says that to communicate the windows host with Docker, you have to use the netsh command and open port, but nothing has worked.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9092 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=9092 connectaddress=172.X.X.X
```

According to the documentation, Docker creates a virtual network for each container.
To test, I have dockerized the configuration service and in the Kafka broker configuration with Spring, I have indicated this way:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka-broker1:29092
```

It has been the only way to be able to connect to Kafka.
So far so good, but what I want is to connect from the windows host which is where I have the VSCode IDE to develop.
I've even made a copy of the code to move it to the WSL host and develop from there, but it doesn't communicate either.

It is true that there is a bug in WSL, any version, that eliminates the resolv.conf file, eliminating all the configuration to access both the internet and other networks, and for now you have to create them manually, this is something minor, I can create a script so that when starting WSL, the file is created.

Compose file Kafka cluster used

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:latest
    container_name: kafka-ui
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=zookeeper-1:2181
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=kafka-local-1
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka-broker1:29092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - kafka-broker1

  # ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information,
  # naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services.
  # It provides distributed coordination for our Kafka cluster.
  # http://zookeeper.apache.org/
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    # ZooKeeper is designed to "fail-fast", so it is important to allow it to
    # restart automatically.
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    # We'll expose the ZK client port so that we can connect to it from our applications.
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/zookeeper-1/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/zookeeper-1/datalog:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888

  ##################################################
  ##################################################
  kafka-broker1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-broker1
    container_name: kafka-broker1
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper-1:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka-broker1:29092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka-broker1:29092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    volumes:
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/kafka-broker1/logs:/var/log/kafka
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/kafka-broker1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
    
  ##################################################
  # To execute command in order to create topics.
  # replication factor 1 and particion 1.
  ##################################################
  kafka-mktopics:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka_mktopics
    networks:
      - kafka_network
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - kafka-broker1
    entrypoint: ['/bin/bash', '-c']
    command: |
      "echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... 
       cub kafka-ready -b kafka-broker1:29092 1 60
       
       echo -e 'Creating default topics' 
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic testkfk
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic orders
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic order-validations
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic warehouse-inventory
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic customers
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic payments
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic platinum
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic gold
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic silver
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic bronze

       echo -e 'Topics was created successfully'
       kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --list
       "

networks:
  kafka_network:
```

@whitespace
the compose file is in the mykafka folder and the network it creates is mykafka_kafka_network.
This is the result

```
[
    {
        "Name": "mykafka_kafka_network",
        "Id": "275189f5502e5b93cc5de0bf456ef07248a09f3d3e5931e617d36901da324b05",
        "Created": "2022-08-15T14:38:55.4024562+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.28.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "02558162fedd616bba22f3f83d7d5ead36dafcdad95bc981a12d04c0da86b508": {
                "Name": "kafka-broker1",
                "EndpointID": "3d25a76e923200b7bf46f98a2d9bf594316776a2174b5d6d11a72345cc69e4e8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "03cf11fa279c6e751d50f7cde7ef53e57cd8c6d5e70c5da34316528f042ac064": {
                "Name": "zookeeper-1",
                "EndpointID": "b121b67471767c573b9817ca54286aefc54c25b172f7a01cdbe94600db42f59c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "263d22dbdcbecd37ac37094e8b9a4c93680fd0ff2d9b9d6e24161103ffb5fb45": {
                "Name": "cmak-manager",
                "EndpointID": "679fee2fd3b704181e93b951655815fd78ac2be9ea6ff7faba2624c5ad2e015a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "kafka_network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "mykafka",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    }
]
```

@OneCricketeer
It doesn't work for me. :-(

I saw this video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACjlvzw4bVE.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACjlvzw4bVE)
My hostname return 2 IP different when execute the command wsl hostname -I on PowerShell.
On Powershell ipconfig return 172.19.224.1 of WSL
Into WSL, ifconfig return eth0 172.19.238.212
When restar are different

This is the complete compose file I used after correction

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  cmak:
    image: ghcr.io/eshepelyuk/dckr/cmak-3.0.0.5:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: cmak-manager
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        aliases:
          - cmak
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: "zookeeper-1:2181"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1

  # ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information,
  # naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services.
  # It provides distributed coordination for our Kafka cluster.
  # http://zookeeper.apache.org/
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    # ZooKeeper is designed to "fail-fast", so it is important to allow it to
    # restart automatically.
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        aliases:
          - zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    # We'll expose the ZK client port so that we can connect to it from our applications.
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/zookeeper-1/data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/zookeeper-1/datalog:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:2888:3888

  ##################################################
  ##################################################
  kafka-broker1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-broker1
    container_name: kafka-broker1
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        aliases:
          - kafka-broker
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper-1:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka-broker1:29092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka-broker1:29092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    volumes:
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/kafka-broker1/logs:/var/log/kafka
      - ./.zks-kfks-target/kafka-broker1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1

  ##################################################
  # To execute command in order to create topics.
  # replication factor 1 and particion 1.
  ##################################################
  kafka-mktopics:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka_mktopics
    networks:
      kafka_network:
        aliases:
          - mktopics
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - kafka-broker1
    entrypoint: ['/bin/bash', '-c']
    command: |
      "echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... 
       cub kafka-ready -b kafka-broker1:29092 1 60
       
       echo -e 'Creating default topics' 
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic testkfk
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic orders
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic order-validations
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic warehouse-inventory
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic customers
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic payments
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic platinum
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic gold
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic silver
       kafka-topics --create --if-not-exists --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 2 --topic bronze

       echo -e 'Topics was created successfully'
       kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka-broker1:29092 --list
       "

networks:
  kafka_network:
    name: argades_kafka_net
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: `networks`, on your docker compose is incomplete, is `kafka_network`, already created. if so what driver is it using.

Comment: It doesn't work with or whitout nertworks.
I added this to test but without result

Comment: what is the output of `docker network inspect kafka_network`

Comment: if you are trying to access, `kafka-broker1`, you will need to do it using IP of that container, `172.28.0.3/16`. You can check if this works.  This ip address will change each time you run `docker-compose`. To set ip address to a static one, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493490/provide-static-ip-to-docker-containers-via-docker-compose) can be followed.

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51630260/connect-to-kafka-running-in-docker if you're using Docker for Windows, and enable WSL2 integration, then ports are automatically forwarded.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've installed Docker on WSL, no windows

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71574027/2308683

Comment: It doesn't work for me. :-(

Comment: There are two related issues. 1) In the advertised listeners - `LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092` - What is `DOCKER_HOST_IP`? Can you remove this and just advertise `127.0.0.1`? 2) Restarts may change the IP of the hypervisor, yes, but you just need to forward a port, not have a static IP address for it. Also, you should put `0.0.0.0` address in `KAFKA_LISTENERS` variable

Comment: Yes!!!!
it works!
The problem was that it modified both the listener and the advertised-listener