# WARN NetworkClient: Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write the stream from kafka using pyspark.
It gives me a warning like this

`WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-a422a51e-b0ef-45cc-bd5c-c327b8881359-1275625627-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-a422a51e-b0ef-45cc-bd5c-c327b8881359-1275625627-driver-0] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-a422a51e-b0ef-45cc-bd5c-c327b8881359-1275625627-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-a422a51e-b0ef-45cc-bd5c-c327b8881359-1275625627-driver-0] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected` and so on ...

I have checked my server.properties and zookeeper.properties, it seems everything is fine

here is the python code that I am using

```
def retrieve_schema(Topic: str) -> str:
    # schema registry
    schema_registry_server = "localhost"
    schema_registry_port = "8081"
    schema_registry_url = "http://" + schema_registry_server + ":" + schema_registry_port

    response_schema =requests.get('{}/subjects/{}value/versions/latest/schema'.format(schema_registry_url, Topic))
    response_schema.raise_for_status()
    schema = response_schema.text
    return schema


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sparkDir = "C:\spark\spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7"
    findspark.init(sparkDir)

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Kafka Pyspark Streaming").getOrCreate()

    topic_name = "ora-WALLET_TRANSACTIONS"
    kafka_bootstrap_server = "localhost:9092"

    # create the schema as a json format
    mySchema_json = retrieve_schema(topic_name)

    sampleDataFrame = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_server) \
        .option("subscribe", topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()

    sampleDataFrame.printSchema()
    avroValues = sampleDataFrame.select(from_avro(data=col("value"), jsonFormatSchema=mySchema_json).alias("value"))
    avroData = avroValues.select("value.TRX_ID", "value.ACCOUNT_NUMBER",
                                 "value.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT", "value.TRANSACTION_DATE")

    avroData.printSchema()

    print("\nStart writing the stream")
    dStream = avroData\
        .writeStream\
        .queryName("data")\
        .format("console")\
        .start()

    #
    dStream.awaitTermination()
```

**EDIT**:
I switch from avro to json converter and I added to the previous code the StructType schema that matchs the records in topic

```
 mySchema = StructType([
        StructField("TRX_ID", StringType(), True),
        StructField("ACCOUNT_NUMBER", StringType(), True),
        StructField("TRANSACTION_AMOUNT", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("TRANSACTION_CURRENCY", StringType(), True),
        StructField("TRANSACTION_DATE", TimestampType(), True),
        StructField("TRANSACTION_REFERENCE_ARN", StringType(), True),
        StructField("REFERENCE_NUMBER", StringType(), True),
        StructField("WALLET_NUMBER", StringType(), True),
        StructField("SOURCE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER", StringType(), True),
        StructField("DESTINATION", StringType(), True),
        StructField("FC_REFERENCE_NUMBER", StringType(), True),
        StructField("TRANSACTION_TYPE", StringType(), True),
        StructField("PROVIDER", StringType(), True),
        StructField("DEST_BANK_CODE", StringType(), True),
        StructField("BILL_KEY", StringType(), True),
        StructField("GHIPS_REF", StringType(), True),
        StructField("USER_CODE", StringType(), True),
        StructField("BANK_CODE", StringType(), True)
       ])
```

And I used from_json instead of from_avro i get the stream back **it has null values**

Comment: According to the error, Kafka is not running

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I don't think so because when i excecute this command `confluent local services status` it shows the kafka is running `Kafka is [UP]`

Comment: That command is not supported on Windows. I assume you run this in WSL2? Spark is running in Windows host, not in your Linux terminal, therefore `localhost:9092` will not be able to connect. [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569699/running-kafka-confluent-platform-on-wsl-2-ubuntu-distribution-and-spring-appli/71574027#71574027) may be useful

Comment: @OneCricketeer should I change the advertised.listeners in server.properties ?

Comment: By default, it should be `localhost:9092`, so no. You will need to change `listeners` to be `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`. And then you need to forward the port assuming you are using WSL2... Or you can run your Spark code in WSL2 rather than from Windows host. Also, by the way, `from_avro` will not work on Schema Registry encoded data

Comment: I switched everything to ubuntu but I still getting an error
```org.apache.spark.SparkException: Malformed records are detected in record parsing. Current parse Mode: FAILFAST. To process malformed records as null result, try setting the option 'mode' as 'PERMISSIVE'.```
I've added .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE") to the previous code but still get the same exception I tried DROPMALFORMED a s well. :( 
by the way i have used from_avro function because i used **io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter** in the jdbc connector properties
@OneCricketeer what should I do to solve this ? Thank You

Comment: As I said, [`from_avro` will not work with Confluent data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry)